# Access global variables through Helper

Tags: javascript, localization, handlebars.js

How can I access a global variable through a helper function in Handlebars.js for the purpose of localization? Here's what I've got so far. The problem I'm seeing is that the parameter 'string' is undefined inside the `registerHelper` anonymous function.

**Template**

```
<span>{{resourceHelper date}}:</span>
```

**String Resources**

```
Resources = {};
Resources['date'] = "Date";
```

**Helper Function**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('resourceHelper', function(string) {
    return Resources[string];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the parameter being passed into the helper was the actual object name within the Handlebars context. So passing `date` obviously didn't work, as there was no associated object in that context. You can, however, pass the values as strings:

```
{{resourceHelper "date"}}
```

This solved my problem with no other changes to the helper function required.